# Does disconnecting the negative reset my clock?

Tags: battery

I took my car to have glow plugs changed and when I had it back was surprised the clock with the time on it wasn’t reset does this mean the plugs wasnt changed? Because you are supposed to disconnect the negative terminal. Or does it not affect the clock because only the black terminal is disconnected? Or would the mechanic have done it without disconnecting?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

One of two things:

- The technician reset the clock after reconnecting the battery.
- The technician didn't disconnect the battery in the first place.

I'm betting the second in this case. While it is good practice to disconnect the battery, not doing so shouldn't cause any issues. Nothing electronically would get hurt by not disconnecting it.

Comment: He didn’t reset the clock I know that. I was concerned he hadn’t done the job, is it common for a mechanic not to disconnect the battery?

Comment: @KaneThomas For all the times I've replaced my own glow plugs, I've never disconnected the battery. As long as the ignition switch is off, the glow plugs get no power, so it's perfectly safe.